# PDO - add values from several rows to get average

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, average

I have a PDO query that returns the number of rows. Each row contains an integer, and what I want to do next is add all the integers together so that I can divide it by the number of rows to get an average. Would I use a foreach loop?

```
$rates = $users->rate_count($id);
$ratecount = count($rates);
```

**Edit: Got it work with SQL - thanks everyone:**

```
public function rate_average($id) {
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT AVG(rate) FROM `ratefeed` WHERE post=?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $id);
    try{
        $query->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
    return $query->fetchColumn();
}


$rateaverage = $users->rate_average($id);
```

Comment: Barring any more detail, yes, that will do, but have you tried this? Does it not work? What database are you using?

Comment: This works, I just don't know how to word the foreach loop to get it to add each row together?

Comment: Why don't you just let MySQL calculate the average?

Comment: The MySQL [`AVG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) function does this. Don't download your entire database to do simple math.

Comment: What you're looking for is `fetchColumn()`, not `fetch()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, in PHP:

```
$count = 0;
$sum = 0;
foreach ($array as $element) {
   $count = $count + 1;
   $sum = $sum + $element;
}
print_r($sum/$count);
```

Nevertheless, as pointed out in the comments, using SQL is your most performant bet. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks, can you look at the edit I made and see if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: `print_r($query_fetch);` to be sure, but I suspect you want `$query_fetch[0]`

Comment: You know you can simplify `$count = $count + 1;` as `$count++`. And instead of having `$count` at all, just do `count($array)`. And if it is an array of numbers, as you have it, you could simplify the whole thing to `array_sum($array) / count($array)`.

Comment: @Mike OP didn't specify types he was using and I wanted to be explicit, feel free to edit the answer to your liking and I'll approve